# UTC Date and Time to any timezone Delphi

Tags: delphi, datetime, utc, delphi-xe6

Using Delphi XE6. I need to be able to convert a UTC date and time to any US timezone.
Right now I have all date time in UTC on my database plus a number for each timezone user. Like 5 for EST.

I have this but it always give me back the same time regardless of the daylight saving.

```
function SendRouteOnCallNotify.GetMyLocalTime(UTCDate,UTCTime: TDateTime; HoursToAdd: Integer): TDateTime;
var
  T: TSystemTime;
  TZ: TTimeZoneInformation;
  DT: TDateTime;
begin
  // Get Current time in UTC
  //GetSystemTime(T);
  ReplaceTime(UTCDate,UTCTime);
  DateTimeToSystemTime(UTCDate,T);
  // Setup Timezone Information for Eastern Time
  TZ.Bias:= 0;

  // DST ends at First Sunday in November at 2am
  TZ.StandardBias:= (HoursToAdd * 60);
  TZ.StandardDate.wYear:= 0;
  TZ.StandardDate.wMonth:= 11; // November
  TZ.StandardDate.wDay:= 1; // First
  TZ.StandardDate.wDayOfWeek:= 0; // Sunday
  TZ.StandardDate.wHour:= 2;
  TZ.StandardDate.wMinute:= 0;
  TZ.StandardDate.wSecond:= 0;
  TZ.StandardDate.wMilliseconds:= 0;

  // DST starts at Second Sunday in March at 2am
  TZ.DaylightBias:= (HoursToAdd * 60);
  TZ.DaylightDate.wYear:= 0;
  TZ.DaylightDate.wMonth:= 3; // March
  TZ.DaylightDate.wDay:= 2; // Second
  TZ.DaylightDate.wDayOfWeek:= 0; // Sunday
  TZ.DaylightDate.wHour:= 2;
  TZ.DaylightDate.wMinute:= 0;
  TZ.DaylightDate.wSecond:= 0;
  TZ.DaylightDate.wMilliseconds:= 0;

  // Convert UTC to Eastern Time
  Win32Check(SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(@TZ, T, T));

  // Convert to and return as TDateTime
  Result := EncodeDate(T.wYear, T.wMonth, T.wDay) +
   EncodeTime(T.wHour, T.wMinute, T.wSecond, T.wMilliSeconds);
end;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you debug, on which line does it deviate from your expectations? And how?

Answer (score 2):

The [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481(v=vs.85).aspx) explains the interesting fields of the `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` structure (abbreviated):

The `TTimeZoneInformation` record has 3 fields to adjust standard time and  daylight saving time (DST) in relation to UTC: `Bias`, `StandardBias` and `DaylightBias`. The normal usage of these are that

- `Bias` holds the difference in minutes between UTC and local (standard) time.
- `StandardBias` holds number of minutes to adjust deviations during standard time. This is usually zero.
- `DaylightBias` holds number of minutes and is added to the `Bias` field to form the total bias used during DST. Usually this is -60.

In your case when you have set the `Bias` field to 0 and adjust the `StandardBias` and `DaylightBias` fields with the number of hours (from your db) you still need to adjust the `DaylightBias` for the extra 60 minutes, f.ex.

```
TZ.StandardBias:= (HoursToAdd * 60);

TZ.DaylightBias:= ((HoursToAdd-1) * 60); // note the -1 hour
```